# How to "combine" two nodes and relationships in neo4j using Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm modeling a "tag cloud" with the graph:

```
(t:Tag {name:'cypher'})-[:IN]->(g:TagGroup)<-[:TAGGED]-(x)
```

IE: A named tag is part of a "TagGroup", to which zero or more nodes are "TAGGED". I chose this design as I want the ability to combine two or more named tags (e.g. "cypher" and "neo4j") so that both `(Tag)`s are `[IN]`the new `(TagGroup)` and the new `(TagGroup)` is the endpoint for the union of all nodes that were previously `[TAGGED]`.

My only (not very pleasing) attempt is:

```
match (t:Tag {name:'cypher'})-[i:IN]->(g:TagGroup),
(t2:Tag {name:'neo4j'})-[:IN]->(g2:TagGroup)<-[y:TAGGED]-(x)
create (t2)-[:IN]->(g) 
create unique (g)<-[:TAGGED]-(x)
with g2 as g2 
match (g2)<-[r]->() delete g2,r
```

My main issues is that it only combines two nodes, and doesn't feel very efficient (although I have no alternatives to compare it with). Ideally I'd be able to combine an arbitrary set of (Tag)s by name.

Any ideas if this can be done with Cypher, and if so, how?

Comment: So, what you are looking to do is take 2 TagGroups and merge them together?

Answer (score 0):

You can use labels instead of creating separate tag groups.

eg. if tag neo4j and cypher come under tag group say XYZ then

```
MERGE (a:Tag {name: "neo4j"})-[:TAGGED]->(x)
MERGE (b:Tag {name: "cypher"})-[:TAGGED]->(x)
set a :XYZ , b :XYZ
```

So next time you want tags of a particular group TAGGED to a particular post x

```
MATCH (a:Tag:XYZ)-[:TAGGED]->(x) return a.name
```

Comment: As I understand it, MERGE creates new nodes and paths, rather than combining the contents on nodes. I don't think your solution will do what I want, which is essentially to be able to treat two existing sets of relationships as one?

Comment: I have assumed that new tags neo4j and cypher are created. Now the set clause will attach a group label XYZ .

Comment: And yes as i began in my solution, i suggested to use labels instead of creating separate tag groups nodes and IN relationships

Comment: No, the names are user-generated, so unknown in advance and we need to group then when they are semantically equivalent